# Como remover cache de js externo?

Tags: javascript, cache

Adicionei em um site uma lib externa que chamava via inclusão de script, ou seja um js que fazia a comunicação com os serviços que essa empresa oferecia. Após essa inclusão eles adicionavam as informações na página.

Até ai tudo certo, porém agora encerramos o contrato e tirei a inclusão desse js externo deles, mas não sei como ainda é carregado no site é como se fosse um cache mas não faz sentido sendo que removi a inclusão desse script, saberiam o por que e como resolver isso?

Answer (score 0):

Navegue ao site e verifique a URL do script. Tente acessar essa URL isoladamente pelo seu navegador. Você descobrirá que uma de duas coisas está a ocorrer:

- O script está hospedado em um servidor que você controla. Você pode então remover o script do endereço no qual se encontra, ou condicionar seu acesso de alguma forma (i.e.: através de uma chave de API ou token de autenticação);
- O script está hospedado em um servidor que você não controla. É trivial copiar um script de uma página qualquer. Seu cliente pode ter feito uma cópia de seu script.